# Computer shut off while running eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jogl

My computer shut off while I was running eclipse due to a power failure. After I restarted it, I can no longer start eclipse. I am running eclipse Luna and the log message I am getting is this:

```
!SESSION 2014-12-01 18:58:51.825 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_67
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_CA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-12-01 18:58:52.410
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Any ideas? I have already tried cleaning eclipse and deleting the lock file in the workspace. I couldn't find any other information relevant to my situation

Comment: Which OS are you on ? edit - sorry i'm blind, just saw win32

Comment: Why is it tagged JOGL???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to debug the problem, a [search for "Unable to acquire application service"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Unable%20to%20acquire%20application%20service&ie=UTF-8) gets some answers that might help.

**But** if you just want to fix the problem, I suggest doing a clean install of Eclipse. It doesn't take long unless you have many added plugins.

That will fix all the Eclipse state without changing your workspace. In my experience, this is effective.

If that doesn't work, then look for broken state in your workspace.

Comment: @themayer the question is "any ideas?" presumably for understanding and fixing eclipse startup. I suggested both how to get more ideas and a reliable way to fix eclipse problems (it's worked for me) excepting problems in the workspace. Eclipse writes to its config files outside the workspace, so this technique is a good one.

Comment: agreed, I didn't read the question. This post came up in the review queue, and it appeared to be a comment. I still don't think it's a great answer, but the question doesn't leave much room for anything better unless you know exactly what causes this problem.

Comment: @theMayer agreed. I clarified the answer by separating the debugging vs. fixing parts. The former is just a beginning but there's little to go on. The latter is more practical.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Start a command prompt

2) "cd" to your Eclipse directory

3) Type this command: `eclipse.exe -clean` (Windows) or `./eclipse -clean` (Linux)

You can also try: `eclipse.exe -initialize`

Comment: I have already tried that and I am getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe search for a folder in your c:\Documents And Settings\<username>\ApplicationData, or in windows 7 c:\Users\<username>\ApplicationData. Eclipse can store configuration files also in there. Not sure where though. Rename or delete the folder if you find it. ApplicationData should be a hidden folder, so be sure to have the option to see hidden folders checked.

Comment: @Marcs do you mean `AppData`? You can type `%AppData%` in the explorer go to path field to jump to `AppData\Roaming`, also.

Comment: Yeah i mean the ´%AppData%´ folder, but i guess i'm not 100% sure where eclipse store data. Just checked that in my case (on windows 8.1) eclipse is storing data in: ´c:\Users\<username>`\.eclipse´.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

The `config.ini` file should specify `org.eclipse.core.runtime@start` in the `osgi.bundles` property. Here is the default `osgi.bundles` property, maybe it was (accidently) changed during some upgrade:

You need to add the following line to the bottom of the eclipse.ini file:

```
-Dosgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start
```